# Swagger documents all those HTTP methods which weren't mapped in Spring Boot Controller class

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using Swagger 3.0.0 for documentation of the HTTP API endpoints generated through my Spring Boot based application. However, when I mapped a controller method to an endpoint, then Swagger created documentation in which it associated that controller with all the HTTP methods possible(even though I explicitly programmed it to be associated with a single HTTP method, say GET). For instance, consider the following code :

```
// Application.java

//required imports

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {
    
    public static void main (String args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean 
    public Docket apiConfigurator () {
        // build the required Docket
    } 

}
```

```
// DataController.java

// required imports

@RestController

public class DataController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns all the data")
    @RequestMapping("/data/allData")
    public String getAllData () {
        // return some data 
    }
}
```

Now, if I were to execute something like this, then Swagger will automatically map the `getAllData ()` method to all HTTP methods (GET, PUT, POST, etc). And this is wrong, because the only method that `getAllData ()` should be associated with is a  basically a GET method.

So, how should I take care of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the specifics, but directly using @RequestMapping annotation for implicitly mapping a GET method to a controller method confuses Swagger. That's why you need to be specific when you're writing down a mapping annotation in presence of Swagger. What I mean to say is that, you need to explicitly tell Spring Boot (and Swagger) that this controller method, say `getAllData ()` is mapped to a HTTP method, say GET by using either :

1. `@RequestMapping (value = "/path/to/get/foobar", method = RequestMethod.GET)` or
2. `@GetMethod ("/path/to/get/foobar")`

This way the Swagger based documentation associates `getAllData ()` with only GET and nothing else.